# Wrong output for reading data from file into program

Tags: c, file, debugging, io

I've been working on a program to read data from file into a program and print it:

Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main()
{
    char *p;
    int e;
    float f;
    static char a[50];
    FILE *fp;
    fp = fopen("new_input.txt", "r");
    if (fp == NULL)
        exit(0);
    while (1)
    {
        p = fgets(a, 50, fp);
        if (p == NULL)
            break;
        printf("%s", a);
        printf("\n");
        fscanf(fp, "%d", &e);
        printf("%d", e);
        printf("\n");
        fscanf(fp, "%f", &f);
        printf("%f", f);
        printf("\n");
    }
    fclose(fp);
    return 0;
}
```

Contents of file new_input.txt are:

```
Girik
12   
19.98   
Nikhil
13
90.89
```

On running on OnlineGdb however I get the following output:

```
Girik 
     
12 
19.980000   
      
     
12  
19.980000 
khil         
13          
90.889999
```

Can someone explain the problem with my code?

I'm concerned about incomplete name "Nikhil" in output and printing of the value 12 and 19.99 twice.

Link to code:
https://onlinegdb.com/r1ufoP8-d

Comment: Apparently the implementation of printf for the `%f` specifier differs on the two platfoms.

Comment: @PaulOgilvie What do you mean?

Comment: Are there empty lines between each line with values in the input? Note: You don't check if `scanf` succeeded.

Comment: @PaulOgilvie Please see the code on OnlineGDB link, it's difficult to type here and explain.

Comment: If you want this consistent, `%.2f`.

Comment: Input and output should be in code blocks. Please take a look to see if the newlines are correct for input and output.

Answer (score 2):

The problem arises because the last `fscanf` does not parse the `\n`, so when the cycle restarts the `fgets` will parse it and print it, naturally the next `fscanf` is not able to parse the string (`"Nikhil"`, which was not parsed), because it expects an `int`, it's downhill from there, as the values are not parsed, what's printed is the old values of `e` and `f` from the previous cycle.

If you change your last `fscanf` so it parses the `\n` everything works fine:

[Live demo](https://onlinegdb.com/TANiyGm6n)

```
while (1)
{
    p = fgets(a, 50, fp);
    if (p == NULL)
        break;
    printf("%s", a);
    fscanf(fp, "%d", &e);
    printf("%d", e);
    printf("\n");
    fscanf(fp, "%f\n", &f); //<--here
    printf("%.2f", f);//.2f specifier so it prints only 2 decimal places
    printf("\n");
}
```

The pointer is also unnecessary you can use `fgets` itself as a condition ***i.e.***:

```
while (fgets(a, sizeof a, fp)) //will read until the end of the file
{
    printf("%s", a);
    //... same code
}
```

Anyway, here is a version you can use that will render you the expected result and output, and, I would argue, is better:

[Live demo](https://onlinegdb.com/ByGk3FUbu)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    int e;
    float f;
    static char a[50];
    FILE *fp;
    fp = fopen("new_input.txt", "r");
    if (fp == NULL){
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    // will parse until \n or 49 characters max (given the container size)
    while (fscanf(fp, " %49[^\n]", a) > 0)
    //                 ^ space - will discard any blank characters         
    {
        printf("%s\n", a);
        if(fscanf(fp, "%d", &e) > 0){
            printf("%d\n", e);
        }
        if(fscanf(fp, "%f", &f) > 0){
            printf("%.2f\n", f);
        }
    }
    fclose(fp);
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

I also added the checks for the `fscanf` returns which is always a good practise.

Or even:

```
//...
while (fscanf(fp, " %49[^\n]%d%f", a, &e, &f) == 3)
{
    printf("%s\n%d\n%.2f\n", a, e, f);
}
//...
```

However, the best solution, I believe, is to parse everything with `fgets` and convert the values with [`sscanf`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf) or [`strtol`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strtol)/[`strtof`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strtof), it's a more robust option. Give it a try.

Comment: @programmer, The problem is a newline charatcter that is not parsed by `fscanf` so it remains and is read next by `fgets`, I added an explanation to my answer, let me know if doubts remain.

Comment: "parse everything with fgets and convert the values with sscanf": yes, that should always be done this way. `scanf` eats characters until it meets one that it doesn't expect, so you end up reading half of an input and the other half stays in the file buffer. This is hard to debug and you can't output a useful message like "this number ... is not valid" since you only got half of it. That's why, BTW, `Nikhil` was half-eaten and only `khil` remained (`scanf` was looking for `NaN` but there seems to be a bug in glibc since only the `N` should have been eaten)

Comment: @xhienne, that is wierd, I didn't realize it, well spotted.

Comment: I'm looking at `_IO_vfscanf_internal`'s code in glibc 2.27 (vfscanf.c) and I can confirm that when searching for "NaN", "Inf" or "Infinity", in case of error, there is a `goto errout` where no `ungetc()` gets called. Therefore, in that case, the last character read is lost, whereas it should have been pushed back into the read buffer. Should it really? Well, I expect so but the standard reads "fscanf pushes back **at most** one input character onto the input stream" so maybe it's not a bug after all.

Comment: @xhienne, it appears so, pending on further investigation, I may post something regarding this matter, when I have the time... So, maybe sometime next year ;)

Comment: @anastaciu It doesn't matter :-) Your answer is good as everything important (to me) is in it: 1. checking `scanf()` return value and 2. using `sscanf()`

Answer (score 0):

For "read data from file into a program and print it", you can use e.g. fgets or fscanf. Both uses are included in the following adaption of your example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main()
{
    char *p;
    int e;
    float f;
    static char a[50];
    FILE *fp;
    
    // use fgets
    printf("\nVersion with using fgets\n\n");
    fp = fopen("new_input.txt", "r");
    if (fp == NULL) exit(0);
    while(fgets(a, 50, fp)!=NULL)
    {
        printf("%s", a);
    }
    fclose(fp);
    
    // use fscanf
    printf("\nVersion with using fscanf\n\n");
    fp = fopen("new_input.txt", "r");
    if (fp == NULL) exit(0);
    while(fscanf(fp,"%s\n",a)!=EOF)
    {
        printf("%s\n", a);
    }
    fclose(fp);    
    
    return 0;
}
```

COMMENTS:

1. Size of a[50] needs to be larger than maximum line size.
2. You can also fscanf for numbers (if you are sure, that it is a number).
3. Check, if string is integer or float (locale) is a new topic.

Another option: With the assumption that you can rely on the format in "new_input.txt" (to account for the comment of Devolus).

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main()
{
    char *p;
    int g;
    float f;
    static char a[50];
    FILE *fp;
    
    fp = fopen("new_input.txt", "r");
    if (fp == NULL) exit(0);
    
    while(fscanf(fp,"%s\n",a)!=EOF){
        printf("%s\n", a);
        fscanf(fp,"%d\n",&g);
        printf("%d\n", g);
        fscanf(fp,"%f\n",&f);
        printf("%f\n", f);
    }
    fclose(fp);    
    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This code does something completely different than what the OP wanted.

Comment: Devolus, please explain Why? This code does "read data from file into a program and print it" - read in both ways, as tried in the question. Question tries with "fgets" and with "fscanf" - so I show both options.

Comment: The OP has an input where the first line is a string following two lines with numbers. Your code reads the whole file as strings which is quite different and also wrong.

Comment: Then you can point to the line where you do the `fscanf("%f")`and `fscanf("%d")`because I must have missed it.

Comment: Devolus: fscanf of numbers is not needed. The numbers can be read and printed as strings. Anyway, I added new code for considering the number as numbers. Please have a look, if that is what you would say is "not mssing something".